# Ansible - preprocess ERB templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ansible

I am using Ansible to provision environments for my Ruby on Rails application.

I wonder whether it is possible to preprocess my ERB templates prior to ansible copy?  Whats the best way to tackle this problem?

The end goal is to have something templates like this:

**my_template.conf.erb**

```
timeout: 2000
secret_key: <%= ENV['THE_SECRET_KEY'] %>
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You have to use jinja2 templates which are pretty similar to erb templates.

**my_template.conf.j2**

```
timeout: 2000
secret_key: {{ secret_key }}
```

In your playbook it would be something like:

```
- name: Template config
  hosts: all
  user: myuser
  sudo: True
  tags: mytag

  vars:
    - secret_key: "{{ lookup('env','THE_SECRET_KEY') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Do template substitution
      template: src=templates/my_template.conf.j2 dest=/etc/myapp/myconf.conf owner=root group=root mode=0644
```